# Lumen + ReactJS routing. Allocate path

Tags: api, reactjs, routes, react-router, lumen-5.2

I have a Lumen application which frontends uses ReactJS and on backend Lumen acts as a rest-api. With ReactJS I use react-router and when I refresh a react route than Lumen tries to find it's own.

```
$app->get('client', 'ApiController@index');
```

is the entry point to my ReactApp and I wonder if I  could allocate all routes like `client/*` for React.

Is there a a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll just have to define one more route:

```
$app->get('client/{namedParamEventhoughYouDoNotUseIt:.+}', 'ApiController@index');
```

Comment: Can you please extend your answer to return a view. For example, `$router->get('/client/.*', function () use ($router) {
        return view('index');
    });`